# Using a generic save button for several different WPF forms

Tags: wpf, command, lob

I have a question about WPF and a LOB application. I would like to have a ribbon control with the buttons: "New", "Save", "Next Record", "Previous Record" and so on.

I would like the buttons to apply to different kind of forms in the application but be available in the Ribbon on top so that the user has the same way of for example adding new items.

Is this possible to achieve with ICommands or RelayCommand or similar? I would like to specify the question further but I'm not sure what I'm looking for in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind the `Command` of the button to a command of the current "view" or document:

```
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding CurrentView.SaveCommand}" />
```